# iOS SwiftUI: How to detect location of UITapGesture on view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiviewrepresentable

Using Mapbox, the map struct conforms to the UIViewRepresentable protocol. In my makeUIView() function, I create a tap gesture recognizer and add it to the map view.

```
struct Map: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Map>) -> MGLMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: Selector("tappedMap"))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Map>) {
        print("Just updated the mapView")
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Map.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(appState: appState, self)
    }

    // other functions that make the struct have functions required by Mapbox 

    func makeCoordinator() -> Map.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
        var control: Map

        //a bunch of delegate functions

        @objc func tappedMap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            let locationInMap = sender.location(in: control)
            let coordinateSet = sender.convert(locationInMap, toCoordinateFrom: control)
        }
    }
}
```

Neither of the lines in the tappedMap function compile properly...also, when I have 'sender: UITapGestureRecognizer' in the parameters of tappedMap, I causes the application to crash when I tap the mapView--If I remove the parameter, then the function is at least called properly without crashing. Please help

Comment: What error/stack trace do you get from the crash? I don't know Mapbox, but I would start with a breakpoint inside `tappedMap` and inspect the object being received there.

Comment: @JohnNimis I don't know where the stack trace is in Xcode...sorry kind of a newbie here--the error that is thrown says Thread 1: ........: unrecognizable selector sent to instance and then that's followed with the memory address I think. That leads me to believe that it's not receiving a UITapGestureRecognizer but something else, is that correct? Also if I set a breakpoint on even the first line of the method (when I make the first line a print statement) the error is still thrown so it's something with what the tappedMap function is receiving or how it's being called

Comment: OK, I'm trying to reproduce the error, but I'm getting a bunch of compiler errors: one is "Class 'Map.Coordinator' has no initializers", and the other have to do with the `mapView` property, which isn't declared in your code sample. Also, are you importing MapKit in any of these files? You might consider naming your `Map` struct differently, in case there is some kind of namespace collision.

Comment: This isn't MapKit, this is MapBox, and you need to have a pod file that imports the correct cocoapods

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, and I've imported Mapbox. I asked because MapKit also defines a struct called `Map`. I only noticed this because my sample project already had some MapKit code in a different file.

Comment: Updated my post to include all the stuff I think you need--Also tried to change the struct name and that had no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the first problem is your selector definition in the tapGesture declaration. Change it to this:

```swift
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.tappedMap(sender:)))
```

Also, you need to manage the priority of gesture recognizers, since MGLMapView includes UIGestureRecognizer logic internally. I found a discussion of [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/ios/maps/api/4.1.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html):

> Adding your own gesture recognizer to MGLMapView will block the
> corresponding gesture recognizer built into MGLMapView. To avoid
> conflicts, define which gesture takes precedence.

You can try this code in your project (pretty much just copied from the linked page above) **EDIT**: I needed to change the order of lines from my original answer:

```swift
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: Selector("tappedMap"))

// HERE'S THE NEW STUFF:
for recognizer in mapView.gestureRecognizers! where recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
    gestureRecognizer.require(toFail: recognizer)
}

mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

**EDIT**: I *was* able to test this.

I'm a little confused by the logic inside your `tappedMap` selector: maybe you meant something like this?

```swift
@objc func tappedMap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let locationInMap = sender.location(in: control.mapView)
    let coordinateSet = sender.view?.convert(locationInMap, to: control.mapView)
}
```

Comment: That is what I meant for the tappedMap function I think (I'm iffy on @objc functions in general though). When I tap on the mapView though, I get a thread error that says 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'. I'm also about to update my original answer because I think you also need to include the updateUIView() function to get it to compile...

Comment: @nickcoding I updated my answer, and was able to verify that it fixes the issue

Comment: It detects where the tap was on the screen but I was trying to imitate the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431459/ios-swift-how-to-add-pinpoint-to-map-on-touch-and-get-detailed-address-of-th where the person taps on the view and that tap is converted to latitude and longitude of where the tap was--I thought that's what the .convert() function did but I think the way you set coordinateSet just converts the position on screen in one view to the same position in the contained view

Comment: Ah, I see! That's pretty cool. In that case, the second line should be: `let coordinateSet = control.mapView.convert(locationInMap, toCoordinateFrom: control.mapView)`

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much! (I'll award the bounty when I can)